# Estimating R90 (radius of a circle expected to include 90% of impacts)

Tags: probability, distributions, estimators, order-statistics, rayleigh-distribution

I want to determine how big a target I can hit with a bow at a certain distance with 90% probability. I place some paper targets at that distance and shoot 20 arrows at them. I have a ruler and a pencil so I can measure distances on paper and do simple arithmetic, but not something complex like MLE.

Impact coordinates mostly follow bivariate normal distribution centered at the target, but sometimes there is some bias, vertical and horizontal variances might not be exactly the same, and occasionally there is an outlier (flier).

[This analysis](http://lstange.github.io/mcgs/) ([source code](https://github.com/lstange/mcgs/)) recommends L-estimators based on 9th miss radius in a 10 shot group, or sum of 6th and 9th miss radiuses in a 10 shot group. Does this approach make sense? Are there better alternatives?

Proposed L-estimators:

- Measure 9th miss radius R9:10 in each of the two 10 shot groups, take the average, multiply by 1.15 to get estimate of R90.
- In a 10 shot group, add 6th miss radius R6:10 and 9th miss radius R9:10. Do it again with the second group and take the average. Multiply by 0.69 to get estimate of R90.

Comment: Please paste in whatever context is necessary to understand & answer your question.
We want this thread to remain valuable even if the link goes dead.

Comment: Most importantly, if you're looking at L-estimators, do you measure radius from sample center or from point of aim?  Because |POI-POA| [follows the Rice distribution](http://ballistipedia.com/index.php?title=Closed_Form_Precision#How_many_sighter_shots_do_you_need.3F), whereas dispersion from POI is Rayleigh distributed.

Comment: I measure radius from point of aim. The goal it to estimate the size of the target I can hit with given probability. I'm not likely to hit the target if my POI is far from POA.

Answer (score 2):

If you're satisfied that a symmetric bivariate normal is an appropriate model (as are most marksmen), then there is [a closed-form solution for this using the Rayleigh distribution](http://ballistipedia.com/index.php?title=Closed_Form_Precision).

When the distribution is parameterized by σ then the Rayleigh CDF gives us $Pr(r \leq \alpha) = 1 - e^{-\alpha^2 / 2 \sigma^2}$.  This probability is more commonly known as a Circular Error Probable (CEP).

You're looking for the 90% CEP, which is thus $\sigma \sqrt{-2 \ln(90\%)}\approx 2.15\sigma$.

The estimator for the Rayleigh parameter σ is not terribly complex if you can measure your sample impact coordinates and have basic spreadsheet functions.  The unbiased estimator for *n* sample shots is computed as follows:

1. Calculate the sample center $(\bar{x}, \bar{y})$.
2. For each sample shot calculate the sample radius $r_i = \sqrt{(x_i - \bar{x})^2 + (y_i - \bar{y})^2}$.
3. The [unbiased Rayleigh estimator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution#Parameter_estimation) is $\widehat{\sigma_R^2} = \frac{n}{n-1} \frac{\sum r_i^2}{2n}$.
4. Use the same [Gaussian correction factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation#Results_for_the_normal_distribution) to remove the bias when taking the square root of $\widehat{\sigma_R^2}$ as when taking the square root of variance.  I.e., ${}^1/c_{G}(n) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{n-1}}\,\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)}$.  Or, in code or spreadsheet formula, $c_{G}(n)=$ `1/EXP(LN(SQRT(2/(N-1))) + GAMMALN(N/2) - GAMMALN((N-1)/2))`.
5. Finally, the unbiased parameter estimate is $\hat{\sigma} = c_G(2n-1) \sqrt{\widehat{\sigma_R^2}}$.

Comment: The problem with MLE (besides the fact that I would need a spreadsheet to do it) is that it's sensitive to outliers. Rayleigh estimator is more robust, and L-estimators are even better.

Comment: @LouisStange - For large *n* (like 20) *cG* is very small, so if you can find your sample center and measure the radius of each point ... well, you might need a calculator.  Order statistics might be "better" in the sense that they're easier, and it would certainly be interesting if you came up with something robust.  But your benchmark there should be [simple measures like Extreme Spread or 50% CEP](http://ballistipedia.com/index.php?title=Describing_Precision#Measures), which have been the standards used by marksmen (including those backed by big military R&D money and statisticians).

Comment: one of my benchmarks is indeed average extreme spread of 5 five-shot groups, commonly known as the NRA protocol. I find that in practice it tends to underestimate R90 because the assumption of perfect zero is not always justified, and that it is also sensitive to outliers. CEP (if measured directly as median miss radius) has higher CV than R9:10, let alone R6:10+R9:10. And if I estimate CEP indirectly via MLE or Rayleigh estimator, I face sensitivity to outliers. Not a problem for military R&D because there are no shooter errors when testing a rifle in a jig/sled.

Comment: @LouisStange - I don't see how the 50% CEP CV could be higher than the CV of radii beyond the closest 5 of 10 shots.  And obviously *sample* CEP *completely disregards* outliers.  In any case, "shooter error" is certainly part of the shot dispersion, but there's some assumption that you will adjust your hold to bring POA roughly in line with POI.  If you can't control the relationship between POA and center of impact I believe you should be looking at the Rice distribution.

Comment: according to formula 3.13 in [Siddiqui paper](http://ballistipedia.com/images/7/7a/Statistical_Inference_for_Rayleigh_Distributions_-_Siddiqui%2C_1964.pdf), optimum unbiased estimator from single order statistic Rk:N is k=0.79681(N+1)-0.39841+1.16312/(N+1), which for N=10 falls between 8 and 9. My simulation results are in line with this, and R9:10 is simply more convenient to find on a target (it's second worst shot). I tried fitting Rice distribution, too, but it's a lot of work and the results were not any better, unless POI shift was very large (and I would just re-zero).

Comment: @LouisStange - Ah ha, now that is very cool!  You should detail that on Ballistipedia, especially if you can characterize the efficiency of those order statistics, either formally or relative to the other standard statistics.  Because, like you said, for small *n* it's really easy to measure the *n*th worst shot!